# When will scene(openURLContexts) or scene(willConnectTo) have multiple urlContexts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

Both [`scene(_:openURLContexts)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene) and [`scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene) (through [`UIScene.ConnectionOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene/connectionoptions)) are given a `Set` of `UIOpenURLContext`'s.

I was wondering in what situations would there be more than one `UIOpenURLContext`? Every implementation I have seen uses `urlContexts.first` rather than iterating through all of the `urlContext`'s.